# Mojave 10.14.5 and homebrew PHP not working properly

Tags: php, homebrew, macos-mojave

I'm trying to install PHP 7.(2|3) with Homebrew on Mojave 10.14.5 and I can't get it to work.

Fresh install of Mojave with only :

- Google Chrome
- Iterm
- Zsh
- Oh My Zsh

Right after Mojave is installed I run the following in my terminal :

- Install Homebrew (command line from the official website)
- `brew install composer`
- `brew install php`
- `composer global require laravel/installer` (composer is in the path)
- `laravel new blog`

It ends up with a segmentation fault :

`[1]    9310 segmentation fault  laravel new blog`

I tried to reboot, uninstall and reinstall PHP/Homebrew/Mojave several times. I always ends up with the same error.

Also tried with php@7.2 and php@7.1 and other packages like wp-cli, it's the same.

I'm desperate, please help.

EDIT WITH MORE INFO :

composer --version:

`Composer version 1.8.6 2019-06-11 15:03:05`

php -v:

```
PHP 7.1.26 (cli) (built: Apr 23 2019 10:38:28) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.26, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

php -i:
[here](https://pastebin.com/ma3Rd63x)

Comment: Make sure your PHP executable is in PATH, i.e. do `which php` and maybe `brew link php`.

Comment: @alx `/usr/local/bin/php` and already linked. Unlink and link again doesn't work.
EDIT : I ran `brew unlink php && brew link --force php`

Comment: Before you attempt to bootstrap the Laravel application, does the rest of PHP work on your system?

What is the output of php -v or php -i?
Also, have you tried creating the new app through composer _instead_ of Laravel's installer (composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog)

Comment: Just tried all that (without fresh install of Mojave), and seems to work fine. Though I had to run it as `~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel new blog`.

Comment: Also, can you update your post with exact versions from `composer --version` and `php --version`?

Comment: I see your versions, look good. Did you try alternative method `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`?

Comment: Tried `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` and it works properly. With valet, I can go to blog.test and see the page.

Comment: Maybe not that good with versions. When I do `brew install php@7.1` I get `PHP 7.1.30 (cli) (built: Jun  1 2019 00:27:45) ( NTS )`.

Comment: @alx Removed all. Native php is working but as soon as I install php with homebrew, it fails. (`brew install php@7.(1,2,3)`and `brew link php@7.(1,2,3) --force`).

Comment: Probably libraries/extensions get mixed due to some `php.ini` settings. But not sure how that could be if you do clean install. The only difference between our systems seem to be `zsh` (using `bash` here).

Comment: @alx Wiped out everything. Fresh install. Installed only Homebrew, PHP 7.3, Composer and Laravel installer with composer. (no zsh, no iterm, nothing else). Still have the issue.
Do you have the latest version of Mojave, Homebrew, PHP like I do? Starting to wonder if my macbook is the problem...

Comment: Yep, Mojave 10.14.5 (18F132) -- latest available, latest PHP 7.3 from homebrew, freshly updated composer, freshly installed laravel installer, homebrew 2.1.6 (June 21st). This is MacBook Pro 13", late 2015. And I have no other ideas how to make laravel/install work. But if composer create-project works for you, that should be enough?

Comment: My issues are when using Valet, while it DOES install then I get seg faults with WP-CLI. I posted about it here https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/c5jylx/macos_mojave_wpcli_homebrew_php_73_laravel_valet/

Comment: So, it appears the problem is fixed on my machine. I really don't know why. I completed my install with python and django. maybe one of these packages solved the issue. The only thing I remember was to install Zlib that was missing and applying a fix for mojave here : https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3438#issuecomment-435169249
But a lot of others packages were installed during the installation. Could be anything